# When a feature spec runs PhantomJS occurs an error 'Could not rendezvous with font server (error 268435459)'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

- Host: OS X El Capitan, Guest: Vagrant (Debian 7)
- Rails 4.2.6
- RSpec 3.4.4
- npm 3.8.9
- PhantomJS 2.1.1
- Poltergeist 1.9.0

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rspec'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'poltergeist'
```

**package.json**

```
dependencies {
  ...
  phantomjs: 2.1.1,
  ...
```

**some_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature 'Feature', js: true do
  scenario 'scenario' do
    # do something
  end
...
```

And when I run this:

```
% bundle exec spring rspec ./spec/features/some_spec.rb
Running via Spring preloader in process 54104

Randomized with seed 18186

Scenario
2016-07-29 12:55:09.161 phantomjs[54113:3059041] Could not rendezvous with font server (error 268435459)
2016-07-29 12:55:09.161 phantomjs[54113:3059041] XType: unable to make a connection to the font daemon!
2016-07-29 12:55:09.161 phantomjs[54113:3059041] registering /System/Library/Fonts/*, /System/Library/Fonts/Base/*, and /Library/Fonts/* locally
```

PhantomJS raised such an error and there was nothing progresses.

I made another pure Rails project and wrote simple spec

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'capybara'
gem 'capybara-webkit'
gem 'poltergeist'
gem 'phantomjs'
gem 'rspec-rails'
```

**spec/examples/simple_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
include Capybara::DSL
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

describe 'some stuff which requires js', :js => true do
  it 'will take a screenshot' do
    visit("http://google.com")
    page.driver.render('./file.png', :full => true)
  end
end
```

Running this spec, a screenshot was successfully saved.
So I think this problem depends only a project.

What shall I do to fix this? Any helps would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing the issue, but my best guess is that some part of the font handling system in OS X has tied itself into a knot.

Based on googling the error, it does not seem to be PhantomJS-exclusive at least. However, I found no explanation of what the exact cause would be.

Rebooting my machine solved the problem for the time being.